# phantomjs: is there a console or log to see what is going on internally?

Tags: python, logging, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Funny one, to us....

We drive phantom from python -> selenium.

Since phantom is non visual, we have no idea what is going on during a test.

We wonder: Is there :

- A log by phantom we can monitor?
- A message viewer that can receive messages from phantom?

We are looking for high level info. Like:

- << time stamp> GET on /pages/page.html
- << time stamp> js function foo called

etc

Comment: No, you can only register to some events in plain PhantomJS, but you won't get a granularity of specific function calls.

Comment: @ArtjomB. We would be happy with any visibility. We don't need visibility to the actual js call, just a high level log of motion (e.g. not hung!). How do we do the event approach you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `--remote-debugger-port=9000` and `--remote-debugger-autorun=true` options when start phantomjs. Then open browser and navigate to `http://localhost:9000`, you will see phantomjs remote debugger console. It's like Chrome console.

NOTE:

Console can be opened in browser, only if there is a web page opened in phantomjs. Following code can be used to open page:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://github.com';

page.open(url, function() {
    // do something...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `service_log_path`. It should save the log of phantomjs.
The example here uses the splinter library, Although you can do the same with selenium.

```
browser = Browser('phantomjs', service_log_path='/var/log/ghostdriver.log')
```